# Consulta Access con c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access

Estoy haciendo una consulta Access en windowsForm me genera error al cambiar las fechas **fijas** por **dateTimePicker** como puedo hacer que la fecha este de la manera correcta, que funcione

```
OleDbDataReader read = MSAConnection.read(@"
    select 
       p.cod,
       #14/3/2018# as Fecha,
       (select  count(*) 
        from Persona p 
        where not exists( select ma.codPersona 
                          from Control ma 
                          where ma.codPersona = p.codPersona 
                          and ma.fecha = #14/3/2018#)) as Total
    from Persona p 
    where not exists( select ma.codPersona 
                      from Control ma 
                      where ma.codPersona = p.codPersona 
                      and ma.fecha = #" + dateTimePicker + "#)");
        while (read.Read())
        {
            int total = Convert.ToInt32(read["Total"]);
            string a = Convert.ToString(read["cod"]);
        }
```

Comment: el problema e tu consulta o en tu aplicacion ??

Comment: la consulta, la aplicacion va todo bien, lo que quiero es reemplazar las fecha fija con el datetimerpickert

Comment: el dateTimePicker tiene propiedras para acceder directamente al ala fecha o al valor contenido .. para que tienes los # entre el datapicker?

Comment: por cierto, sería muy útil que incluyas el valor que le estás mandando a la variable dateTimePicker

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   p.cod,
   #14/3/2018# as Fecha,
   (select  count(*) 
    from Persona p 
    where not exists( select ma.codPersona 
                      from Control ma 
                      where ma.codPersona = p.codPersona 
                      and ma.fecha = #14/3/2018#)) as Total
from Persona p 
where not exists( select ma.codPersona 
                  from Control ma 
                  where ma.codPersona = p.codPersona 
                  and ma.fecha = '#' + dateTimePicker + '#'));


        while (read.Read())
        {
            int total = Convert.ToInt32(read["Total"]);
            string a = Convert.ToString(read["cod"]);
        }
```

Comment: dentro el read. pierde el hilo del string de consulta

Comment: como habías puesto solamente la consulta sin dar más detalles (https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/146865/1), esta fue la respuesta, al haber editado la pregunta con esa línea del data reader, la situación cambia (https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/146865/3)

Comment: esacto,  solo es editar,

Answer (score 0):

Que te parece ?

```
OleDbDataReader read = MSAConnection.read(@"
    select 
       p.cod,
       #" + dateTimePickerFalta.Value.ToShortDateString() + @"# as Fecha,
       (select  count(*) 
        from Persona p 
        where not exists( select ma.codPersona 
                          from Control ma 
                          where ma.codPersona = p.codPersona 
                          and ma.fecha = #" + dateTimePickerFalta.Value.ToShortDateString() + @"#)) as Total
    from Persona p 
    where not exists( select ma.codPersona 
                      from Control ma 
                      where ma.codPersona = p.codPersona 
                      and ma.fecha = #" + dateTimePickerFalta.Value.ToShortDateString() + "#)");
        while (read.Read())
        {
            int total = Convert.ToInt32(read["Total"]);
            string a = Convert.ToString(read["cod"]);
        }
```